# How to resolve the 'fs' module required by Angular for Vimeo SDK

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, fs, vimeo-api

I am trying to build an angular app that let the users directly upload to vimeo an then view the file contents from Vimeo.

I am doing it for the first time and hence following the official vimeo [guide](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start) and SDK.

However, after I installed the vimeo package from npm, the app fails to compile saying

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vimeo/lib/vimeo.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\MySpace\Code\1-nagarro-skills-web\node_modules\vimeo\lib'
```

It appears that the node build for Angular doesn't support filesystem module since v6. The vimeo module however needs it for its operation.

How can I get around this problem and let the vimeo module work on my angular app.

I tried finding solution and found that one of the way is to set `fs: empty` in webpack config. This too is not possible now as the webpack ejection is not supported.

Can someone please guide the way around this.

P.S: After a deepr research, I found that the Angular team has removed support of many modules from the node shipped for the browser and supplied an empty object at their places. I understand the significance of removing modules like 'os' and other which are not used by browser. However, when consented by user, a file upload or file read seems to be a useful case as is the case in the vimeo sdk here.

Is it then not possible to use the vimeo SDK with browser ?

Answer (score 2):

The vimeo SDK is designed to work on a server-side environment implemented with PHP, NodeJS or Python. The object `fs` is refered to NodeJS file system utilities and therefore not available in the browser. Since Angular is a browser application, these two are not compatible. Use the vimeo SDK inside a backend application and the [vimeo Player SDK](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk) in your frontend Angular application.

Comment: Thanks @Felix. I have come to a similar understanding myself. However, what I fail to understand is that if I can request a video file from the user browser and send it to my server-side setup, why isn't it possible to directly send it to vimeo server.